# LyX does not compile files because of inputenc error

Tags: utf-8, latex, lyx

When I try to compile any document in LyX, I get this message:

```
Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte 179
```

Nothing I found on the web is working. Neither changing the preamble nor setting the LyX itself. I also tried to change the coding in the external program. It turned out that I was left with dozens of files that are useless because I can not compile either old or new ones.

How to force LyX to create a file that can be compiled? The file is to be in Polish.

Comment: Cross-post here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453179

Comment: What character set is being used in your LyX and LaTeX files?

Comment: Answering my own comment - based on that error and the sample LyX file in the crosspost, you're using ISO-8859-16 aka Latin-10. So try `\usepackage[latin10]{inputenc}` instead and see if that helps. Or just convert all your files to UTF-8.

Comment: ISO-8859-2 / Latin-2 is another optionm or Windows CP1250; they and Latin-10 use character 179 for LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE,so maybe`'\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}`? Weird thing is that the LyX documentation says it should be using UTF-8 as its native file format, so how did you even make a .lyx file in what appears to be a Latin-X encoding? Editing the files in something other than LyX?

Comment: I checked the lyx file in another program and it is encoded as utf8. None of the coding you proposed for me works. Problems began after the MiKTeX upgrade and I'm starting to think that MiKTeX is guilty here.